# Recursive list inside dict? - python

Tags: python

I have started learning Python not long ago, and I'm trying to do recursive function for my list. This is the function:

```py
def get_employee(j, field, value):
    res = j
    for x in res:
            if x['Name'] == field and x['Value'] == value:
                return res
            elif "Properties" not in x:
                if x is not None:
                    continue
            elif "Properties" in x:
                return get_employee(x['Properties'], field, value)
```

And this is my JSON:

```
[{
        "Value": "Sales",
        "Name": "Department",
        "Properties": [{
            "Value": "US",
            "Name": "Country",
            "Properties": [{
                    "Value": "Employee",
                    "Name": "EmployeeType",
                    "Properties": [{
                            "Value": "Manya Bishter",
                            "Name": "EmployeeFullName",
                            "Properties": [{
                                    "Value": 1111,
                                    "Name": "EmployeeID"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Manya",
                                    "Name": "EmployeeFirstName"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Bishter",
                                    "Name": "EmployeeLastName"
                                }

                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": "Michael Ort",
                            "Name": "EmployeeFullName",
                            "Properties": [{
                                    "Value": 1112,
                                    "Name": "EmployeeID"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Michael",
                                    "Name": "EmployeeFirstName"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Ort",
                                    "Name": "EmployeeLastName"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Value": "Manager",
                    "Name": "EmployeeType",
                    "Properties": [{
                        "Value": "Nick Fair",
                        "Name": "EmployeeFullName",
                        "Properties": [{
                                "Value": 1113,
                                "Name": "EmployeeID"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Nick",
                                "Name": "EmployeeFirstName"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Fair",
                                "Name": "EmployeeLastName"
                            }
                        ]
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "Value": "Marketing",
        "Name": "Department",
        "Properties": [{
            "Value": "US",
            "Name": "Country",
            "Properties": [{
                "Value": "Employee",
                "Name": "EmployeeType",
                "Properties": [{
                    "Value": "Tamta Hiresh",
                    "Name": "EmployeeFullName",
                    "Properties": [{
                            "Value": 1121,
                            "Name": "EmployeeID"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": "Tamta",
                            "Name": "EmployeeFirstName"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": "Hiresh",
                            "Name": "EmployeeLastName"
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            }]

        }]
    }

]
```

The function work only on Manya, but nowhere else.

For example, if I do this:

```py
print(get_employee(myjson, "EmployeeFirstName", "Nick"))
```

It will print:

```
[{'Value': 1111, 'Name': 'EmployeeID'}, {'Value': 'Manya', 'Name': 'EmployeeFirstName'}, {'Value': 'Bishter', 'Name': 'EmployeeLastName'}]
```

But for others (like `Nick`), it will return `None`.

Can you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: `JSON` is a language-independent *string representation* of a data structure. What you have is a Python `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```py
def get_employee(data, field, value):
    result = []
    def recursor(j, field, value):
        res = j
        for x in res:
            if x['Name'] == field and x['Value'] == value:
                result.append(res)
            elif "Properties" not in x:
                if x is not None:
                    continue
            elif "Properties" in x:
                recursor(x['Properties'], field, value)
    recursor(data,field,value)
    return result
```

The problem with your recursive function is that, once it hits `return get_employee(x['Properties'], field, value)`; it will stop the outer for loop `for x in res:` . Thus it will never run on the next item in your list.

Comment: Thank you! its worked!
What if I would like to print the whole department? like marketing? when I'm trying to print marketing department it prints the whole json
print(get_employee(myjson, "Department", "Marketing"))

Comment: @AlexKostin You can change `result.append(res)` to `result.append(x)` in the above code.