# python recursive dict search in list

Tags: python

I need some help recursively searching a python dict that contains nested lists.

I have a structure like the below example. The value of key "c" is a list of one or more dicts. The structure can be nested multiple times (as you can see in the second item), but the pattern is the same. In all likelihood, the nested depth will probably not be more than 5 deep.

My objective (in this example) is to find all occurrences of ref = 'hij789', **no matter where they occur** (however deep they are nested) and then add the missing 'b' = 'something' to each occurrence.

```
{
  'ref': 'abc123',
  'a': 'something',
  'b': 'something',
  'c': [{
    'ref': 'def456',
    'a': 'something',
    'b': 'something',
    'c': [{
      'ref': 'hij789',
      'a': 'something'
      }]
  },{
    'ref': 'klm012',
    'a': 'something',
    'b': 'something',
    'c': [{
      'ref': 'nop345',
      'a': 'something',
      'b': 'something',
      'c': [{
        'ref': 'hij789',
        'a': 'something'
      }]
    }]
  },{
    'ref': 'qrs678',
    'a': 'something',
    'b': 'something',
    'c': [{
      'ref': 'tuv901',
      'a': 'something'
    }]
  }]
}
```

I first tried something like this, but it of course does not search beyond the first nested dict:

```
l = next((n for n in mydict['c'] if n['ref'] == 'myref'), None)
l['b'] = 'somevalue'
```

I also tried a variation of this, but could not make it work:
[Recursive list inside dict? - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646525/recursive-list-inside-dict-python)

Is there a relatively straightforward way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this will do the job:

```py
def search_and_modify(data):
    if data.get("ref", None) == "hij789":
        data["b"] = "something"

    for dictionarie in data.get("c", []):
        search_and_modify(dictionarie)
```

For your example data the output would be:

```
{
    "ref": "abc123",
    "a": "something",
    "b": "something",
    "c": [
        {
            "ref": "def456",
            "a": "something",
            "b": "something",
            "c": [{"ref": "hij789", "a": "something", "b": "something"}],
        },
        {
            "ref": "klm012",
            "a": "something",
            "b": "something",
            "c": [
                {
                    "ref": "nop345",
                    "a": "something",
                    "b": "something",
                    "c": [{"ref": "hij789", "a": "something", "b": "something"}],
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "ref": "qrs678",
            "a": "something",
            "b": "something",
            "c": [{"ref": "tuv901", "a": "something"}],
        },
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a function like this:

```py
def process_dict(my_dict):
    if my_dict['ref'] == 'hij789':
        my_dict['b'] = 'something'
    if 'c' in my_dict:
        for d in my_dict['c']:
            process_dict(d)
```

and just use

```
process_dict(my_dict)
```

to produce the desired result, assuming I understood your outcome correctly

That assumes all dictionaries you provide will have a 'ref' entry. If that's not guaranteed, you can simply add another condition at the front of the `if` statement with `'ref' in my_dict`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```py
def read_data(data: dict) -> None:
    for key, value in data.items():
        if key == 'ref' and value == "hij789":
            print(value)
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for record in value:
                read_data(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

the following function iterates over the dictionary and when it '*detects*' that the value is of the **list** data type instance it iterates over its values verifying that the reference is equal to `'hij789'` which in this case is equal to the `ref` variable for the extract function call, then we add the item `'b':'something'` using the *`update`* method.

```py
def extract(data, ref):
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for data_item in v:
                if data_item.get('ref') == ref and data_item.get('b')==None:
                    data_item.update({'b': 'something'})
            for n in range(len(v)):
                extract(v[n], ref)
    return data
```

```
>>> data = extract(data, 'hij789')
```

output:

```
{'ref': 'abc123', 'a': 'something', 'b': 'something', 'c': [{'ref': 'def456', 'a': 'something', 'b': 'something', 'c': [{'ref': 'hij789', 'a': 'something', 'b': 'something'}]}, {'ref': 'klm012', 'a': 'something', 'b': 'something', 'c': [{'ref': 'nop345', 'a': 'something', 'b': 'something', 'c': [{'ref': 'hij789', 'a': 'something', 'b': 'something'}]}]}, {'ref': 'qrs678', 'a': 'something', 'b': 'something', 'c': [{'ref': 'tuv901', 'a': 'something'}]}]}
```

changed values can be accessed as follows

```
print(data['c'][0]['c'])
print(data['c'][1]['c'][0]['c'])
>>> [{'ref': 'hij789', 'a': 'something', 'b': 'something'}]
>>> [{'ref': 'hij789', 'a': 'something', 'b': 'something'}]
```